# What representation should I choose for numerical computation of hypergeometric function ${}_2 F_1(1+i\eta, 2; 2+i\eta; x)$ where $|x|=1$

Tags: numerical-methods, complex-numbers, special-functions

I have a task - to plot graphics of the function:

$$
I(E) = \frac{16i \pi k \mu}{(\beta - ik)^{4}} \frac{1}{1 + i\eta} {}_2 F_1(1+i\eta, 2; 2 + i \eta; x)
$$

where

$$
x = \left( \frac{\beta + ik}{\beta - ik} \right)^2
$$
$$
k = \sqrt{\frac{\mu E}{20.9006}}
$$
$$
\eta = 0.15748 \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{E}}
$$
$$
\mu = \frac{m_d m_t}{m_d + m_t} \approx 1.2
$$

For task simplicity, $\beta = 1$. But in future I have to find it from the next equation:

$$
\left( \frac{\beta - ik}{\beta + ik} \right)^{2i\eta} = e^{4 \eta arctg{\frac{k}{\beta}}}, \beta \in \mathbb{R}
$$

Energy parameter $E \in (0, 1]$ MeV, $i$ - is the imaginary unit.

Now my problem is the numerical calculation of the hypergeometric function ${}_2 F_1 (a, b; c; x)$. It is known that the hypergeometric function has a lot of representations. For example, there is a formula of Euler. But it requires that $Re (c) > Re (b) > 0$ and  $|x| < 1$.

**Question**: What method or representation should I use to compute such type of hypergeometric function?

Service [wolfram-alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2F1%282%2C+1%2Bi%2a%280.15748%2asqrt%281.2%2Ft%29%29%3B+2%2Bi%2a%280.15748%2asqrt%281.2%2Ft%29%29%3B+%28%281+%2B+i%2asqrt%281.2+%2a+t%2F+20.9006%29%29%2F%281-i%2asqrt%281.2+%2a+t%2F+20.9006%29%29%29%5E2%29) computes this function with no error...

Comment: Numerical recipes advice to solve the hypergeometric differential equation along a path (which does not intersect the branch cut at $x\in[1,\infty)$) starting from the circle $|x|=1/2$ where the series converges.

Comment: Your numerator and denominator parameters are complex? Interesting. Where did this come from?

Comment: @Fabian: to quote their words, "it's like swatting a fly with a golden brick". It works, but I'm sure there are more efficient ways of going about this. I'll have to do some digging...

Comment: @J.M. for sure. But then one has to use different methods depending on $x$ (which I guess the OP wanted to avoid).

Comment: @J.M. no, they are real(if you speak about $\eta, \beta, k, mu$). this is from physics - it is some kind of differential cross section for Helium. or similar.

Comment: @J.M. You say that direct numerical solving of hypergeometric equation hard task, isn't it?

Comment: No, I meant the arguments of your hypergeometric function. $\eta$ is real, so indeed $1+i\eta$ is complex. And yes, the numerics will be tough. As I said, I need to think about this...

Comment: In the meantime, you might appreciate the use of [Pfaff's transformation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1) as a starting point: $${}_2 F_1\left({{1+i\eta,2}\atop{2+i\eta}}\mid x\right)=\frac1{(x-1)^2}{}_2 F_1\left({{1,2}\atop{2+i\eta}}\mid \frac{x}{x-1}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $E > 0$, $x \not= 1$. Thus, the hypergeometric function ${}_2 F_1(1+i \eta, 2 ; 2+ i \eta ; x)$ is defined. Using Euler's [integral representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/01/01/0001/) with $a=2$, $b=1+ i \eta$ and $c = 2 + i \eta$, we get:
$$
    {}_2 F_1(1+i \eta, 2 ; 2+ i \eta ; x) = (1+ i \eta) \int_0^1 t^{i \eta} (1- t x)^{-2} \mathrm{d} t
$$
The integral is convergent for real $\eta$ and complex $x$ not on $[1, \infty)$.

Apart from the integral representation, you may find the work by Joshua Willis on "[Acceleration of generalized hypergeometric functions through precise remainder asymptotics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3003)" right on for your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use exactly this integral to compute hypergeometric function. I compute it using Simpson method, and all works for me. My problem was in computation of Gamma functions which have to stand before the integral - but you have reduce the fraction and simplified my task!